# How can I disable vcs_info for a specific repository?

Tags: zsh

I enabled `vcs_info` like so:

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats '(%b)'

set_prompt() {
    vcs_info

    print -n "[%~]${vcs_info_msg_0_}%# " # Directory and VCS info (if any).
}

PROMPT=$'$(set_prompt)'
```

This works well, but I recently made my `$HOME` a git repository to manage my dotfile better, so now every time the working directory is `/home/martin` or a subdirectory that doesn't have a git repo of its own, it prints the branch name of the `/home/martin` repo.

I'd like to ignore the repo in `/home/martin`, but *not* any others, such as `/home/martin/code/project`. I tried using `disable-patterns`:

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' disable-patterns "${(b)HOME}/(|/*)"
```

But that will disable it for git repos in a subdirectory of `$HOME` too, which isn't what I want.

I tried disabling it with:

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*:martin' enable NONE
```

But that doesn't seem to take any effect. I also tried blanking the message:

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*:martin' formats ''
```

And now my prompt is `[~]a:%`, so I set it to a zero-width space:

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*:martin' formats "\u200b"
```

And that seems to work; but it seems a bit of a hack.

How can I disable `vcs_info` for a specific repo?

Answer (score 1):

The following works

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:*:*:martin' formats "%0.0r"
```

In this case the `%0.0r` specifier says to use the repository name but display it as 0 width string.

See the zsh [zformat](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fzutil-Module) utility as this is what formats uses.